# Prompting user for multiple items and calculating total cost in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, validation, user-input, custom-error-handling

I'm working on a Python program that allows users to place an order by inputting items, one per line, until they press Ctrl+D to end their input. After each input, I want to display the total cost of all items inputted once the user presses Ctrl+D, with a dollar sign ($) prefix and formatted to two decimal places. The user's input should be case-insensitive, and I want to ignore any input that is not a valid item from a predefined menu.Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
food_menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }

cost = []

while True:
    try:
        item = input("Item: ").title()
        if item in food_menu:
            cost.append(food_menu\[item\])
        else:
            continue
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break

total = sum(cost)
print("Total: $", f"{total:.2f}", sep="")
```

The issue I'm facing is that if I want to input multiple instances of the same item, such as "taco", "taco" and "quesadilla," I have to press Enter after each item and then when I'm prompted for the fourth time I'm able to press Ctrl+D and get the total amount. Ideally, I would like to be able to input "taco", "taco" and "quesadilla" with just two enters and one Ctrl+D, i.e. I'm only prompted thrice and use Ctrl-D instead of thrid 'enter'. How can I modify my code to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt for the script:

- The input can now contain multiple items (separated with spaces)
- Partial matching - as long as it only matches one item on the list (i.E. "Bo" for "Bowls")
- Matching of uppercase letters (i.e.: TS for "Tortilla Salad")
- Added "exit" for ending the script without Ctrl+D

```
import re

# Get the Uppercase characters of a string (i.E.: "Tortilla Salad" => "TS")
def getUpperChars(string):
    return "".join([char for char in string if char.isupper()]).upper()

food_menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}

cost = []
loop = True
while loop:
    try:
        items = input("Enter items from the menu (separated by blanks) (or 'exit' to quit): ")

        # Split at \s but don't split at "Super"
        entered_items = re.split(r'(?<!Super)\s', items)

        for item in entered_items:
            uppercase_match = [key for key in food_menu if (item == getUpperChars(key))]
            matching_keys = [key for key in food_menu if (item.lower() in key.lower())]
            
            if item.lower() == "exit":
                loop = False
                break
            elif item.title() in food_menu:
                chosen_item = item.title()
            elif len(uppercase_match) == 1:
                chosen_item = uppercase_match[0]
            elif len(matching_keys) == 1:
                chosen_item = matching_keys[0]
            else:
                print("Invalid item. Please try again.")
                print(f"The keys containing '{item}': {matching_keys}")
                continue

            cost.append(food_menu[chosen_item])
            print(f"Added {chosen_item} for {food_menu[chosen_item]} to the list.")
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break
    
total_cost = sum(cost)
print(f"\nTotal: ${total_cost:.2f}")
```

When entered `taco taco quesadilla` the result is:

```
Added Taco for 3.0 to the list.
Added Taco for 3.0 to the list.
Added Quesadilla for 8.5 to the list.

Total: $14.50
```

Comment: thanks man, but is there a way you can do it without importing any modules since this assignment was assigned before we were taught libraries. @DTNGNR

Comment: The problem with splitting the input at spaces is that you are using items like "Super Burrito" which we don't want to split into "Super" and "Burrito". You could do two thinks to get rid of the imported module "re": 1) Replace all spaces in the dict food_menu with a minus (i.e. "Super-Burrito") 2) Enter multiple items with commas and use `entered_items = items.split(",")` to split the entered string and add a `item=item.strip()` in the first line of your for loop. I hope that helps!